# ajax-datatables-rails : how do I define in array format at data method and access at javascript ?

Tags: datatable, ruby-on-rails-5.2

According to the document [link](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails) version: 1.0.0

For Map data

```
def data
  records.map do |record|
    {
      id:         record.id,
      first_name: record.first_name,
      last_name:  record.last_name,
      email:      record.email,
      bio:        record.bio,
      DT_RowId:   record.id, # This will automagically set the id attribute on the corresponding <tr> in the datatable
    }
  end
end
```

plain javascript:

users.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#users-datatable').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": $('#users-datatable').data('source'),
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "columns": [
      {"data": "id"},
      {"data": "first_name"},
      {"data": "last_name"},
      {"data": "email"},
      {"data": "bio"}
    ]
    // pagingType is optional, if you want full pagination controls.
    // Check dataTables documentation to learn more about
    // available options.
  });
});
```

This works. How can I use array in map data and call it in java script columns.

Map data example

```
def data
      records.map do |record|
        [record.id, record.first_name, record.last_name, record.email, record.bio]
      end
end
```

next, how to call in javascript?

```
"columns": [
      {"data": ??},
      {"data": ??},
      {"data": ??},
      {"data": ??},
      {"data": ??}
    ]
```